# Add a Video Frame in Player

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to Implement movie player with the cropping functionality.
I need to show full video in one frame and user can select the vedio portion which he wants to crop. 
This is the example image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this is nice video trimmer library for iOS
https://github.com/itsmeichigo/ICGVideoTrimmer

Comment: thank you so much... this is exactly what i want.. you saved my lots of time. :)